# How to write Insert Query in Nopcommerce Plugin?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am creating a plug-in in nopcommerce.

In that plug-in i have created one table and now i want to insert record in that table, but don't know how to write query in nopcommere.

Can anyone provide me an example of writing Insert, Delete & Update queries in nopcommerce plug-in?

Comment: nopcommerce is a front end software you can access with the browser. It uses a SQL db so there is nothing different than sql to access the db. Which is your problem?

Comment: you mentioned it uses entity framework.  it sounds like you are really looking for information on how to use entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

nopcommerce got a MS SQL Database
so queries should be like this:

> INSERT INTO Tablename (column1, column2, ...) VALUES(value1, value2,...)
>
> UPDATE Tablename SET Column1 = value1,  Column2 = value2
>
> DELETE * FROM Tablename WHERE Column = value

Comment: Actually Nopcommerce is using EntityFramework and i don't know how to Insert, Delete or Update records from database using EntityFramewok.